# Switch Text Output Every 5 days in PHP

Tags: php

I have a function that prints out each day from July 21, 2014 through July 31, 2015.  Every 5 days, I want to add an extra line break and switch the name of the person responsible for that five day block.

What I have write now puts person 1 for four days, and person 2 for one day, then person one again for five days.  It needs to be 5 days for person one 5 days for person 2, then 5 days for person one again and so on.

Thank you in advance!

```
<?php

$p = new DatePeriod(
  new DateTime('2014-07-21'),
  new DateInterval('P1D'),
  (new DateTime('2015-07-31'))->modify('+1 day')
);

$counter = 1;

foreach ($p as $d) {

  if ($counter % 5 == 0) {
    echo '<br />Person 1: ' . $d->format('m/d/Y') . "<br /><br />";
  } else {
    echo 'Person 2: ' . $d->format('m/d/Y') . "<br />";
  }
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: And how do you store/track these 5 day periods? as every time the script is accessed, `$p` will be overwritten/re instantiated.

Comment: How so if I'm hard-coding the dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's an option that achieves what you want](https://eval.in/173506), but as Darren mentioned - unless you only run this script once, as soon as the start date changes your "roster" will change too:

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($p as $d) {
    if($counter++ <= 5) {
        echo '<br />Person 1: ' . $d->format('m/d/Y') . "<br /><br />" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'Person 2: ' . $d->format('m/d/Y') . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    if($counter > 10)
        $counter = 1; // reset to original
}
```